# SQL Server: Report the most recent record if it does not contain NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have the following table, employees:

```
employee_name contract_end_date
Nancy         03/01/2019
Nancy         02/01/2019
Nancy         01/01/2019
John          03/01/2019
John          02/01/2019
John          01/01/2019
John          NULL
```

In the scenario above, I want to report Nancy's most recent record because she is does not have an active record (does not have NULL in the contract_end_date), this is what I have:

```
SELECT employee_name , MAX(contract_end_date) as contract_end_date 
FROM [dbo].[employees_test]
WHERE contract_end_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY employee_name
```

I am also getting John in the output from the query above:

```
employee_name   contract_end_date
John            2019-03-01
Nancy           2019-03-01
```

What should I change in the code to get:

```
Nancy           2019-03-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use row_number and subquery to filter out the null records as below:

```
;with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by employee_name order by contract_end_date desc) as rown from #employee 
    where employee_name not in (
        select employee_name from #employee where contract_end_date is null
    )
)
select employee_name, contract_end_date from cte where rown = 1
```

Query attached here https://rextester.com/DMG55580

Answer (score 1):

NULL is excluded in the aggregation functions. You can assign a special value for NULL:

```
SELECT employee_name , MAX(ISNULL(contract_end_date,N'9999-12-31')) as contract_end_date 
FROM [dbo].[employees_test]
GROUP BY employee_name
HAVING MAX(ISNULL(contract_end_date,N'9999-12-31'))<>N'9999-12-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is returning the unique names and max end dates from any record that is not null in the contract_end_date.

The quickest fix I have is to just exclude any names in your table that have a null in the contract_end_date using a subquery.

```
SELECT  employee_name, MAX(contract_end_date) as "contract_end_date"
FROM    [dbo].[employees_test]
WHERE   employee_name not in (SELECT employee_name
                              FROM   [dbo].[employees_test]
                              WHERE  contract_end_date is null
                              GROUP  BY employee_name);
```

There is probably a more optimized approach which may or may not be necessary depending on table size.

Answer (score 0):

You just want `TOP (1)`, you don't need any aggregation:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
       employee_name,
       contract_end_date
FROM dbo.employees_test
WHERE contract_end_date IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY contract_end_date DESC;
```

Edit: Crystal ball time:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       employee_name,
       contract_end_date
FROM dbo.employees_test
WHERE contract_end_date IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY contract_end_date desc);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Top (1) will not work in the cause if I have to report multiple employees who are no longer with the company. Thank you tho!

Comment: I've added a Crystal Ball answer for you, @David.